# Non-Admin Users Can't Use on Prem Custom Connector

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app that uses a custom connector for an on premise data source. I am using an on-prem PowerBI Gateway to route the traffic for the custom connector. I have the checkbox marked to allow custom connectors through:

[image]

The app and connector work great for my own O365 user with no issues. I shared it with a non-admin user and they were unable to get past the connector's Basic authentication. The error was saying the did not have BI gateway permissions, and it stopped the request before it could even connect to my on-prem data source. The only way I have gotten this to work is to make my user an Admin on my BI Gateway. This is not a realistic option, as I want to distribute the app across my organization.

**How can I give non-admin power app users permission to access my custom data source through my on-prem gateway?**

For reference sake, I have confirmed that it is not a licensing issue on the Power Apps side. I have users who have a full admin power apps license, and others who are licensed for D365 who should have acess to on-prem data and custom connectors:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2085130&clcid=0x409